# Multiple events and multi threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, events, .net-4.6

I have a service that raises multiple events, some of them can be raised at the same time. I need to process those events and run a potentially long running method based on the event arguments.
What I did is to create a `BlockingCollection<T>` that will store the events an a `Task` that will keep taking one event at a time until it will be signaled to stop using a `CancellationTokenSource`.
My concern is that I'm not handling the synchronization good enough.
This is the class that handles everything (it's used as a `WPF ViewModel`):

```
public class EventsTest
{
    //private fields
    private BlockingCollection<IoEventArgs> _queue;
    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
    private IoService _ioService;
    private Task _workerTask;
    private static EventWaitHandle _eventWaiter;

    public EventsTest()
    {
        _queue = new BlockingCollection<IoEventArgs>();
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _eventWaiter = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

        //this is the object that raises multiple events
        _ioService = new IoService();
        _ioService.IoEvent += _ioService_IoEvent;

        //Start Listening
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(StartListening, _tokenSource, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    //IO events listener
    private void _ioService_IoEvent(string desc, int portNum)
    {
        //add events to a blocking collection
        _queue.Add(new IoEventArgs() { Description = desc, PortNum = portNum });
    }

    private void StartListening(object dummy)
    {
        //process the events one at a time
        while (!_tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var eve = _queue.Take();
            switch (eve.PortNum)
            {
                case 0:
                    LongRunningMethod(eve.Description);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //invoke a long running method
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    //sample long running method
    private void LongRunningMethod(string data)
    {
        _eventWaiter.WaitOne(10000);
    }
}
```

How can I make this process more robust in terms of thread safety?
Will adding a `lock` around each method implementation improve the safety of the process?

Answer (score 1):

Your `.Take()` won't be canceled so you might wait forever there.

You could pass the token on:

```
var eve = _queue.Take(_tokenSource);
```

but then you would have to handle the exception.

A better approach would be the TryTake(out eve, 1000, _tokenSource) and steer with the returned boolean.

Or forget about the CancellationToken and just use `AddingComplete()`

Comment: passing the `_tokenSource` is not permitted: `cannot convert from 'System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource' to 'System.Threading.CancellationToken'`. Do I need to create a separate `CancellationToken` for this?

Comment: Yes, the Source has a .Token property.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a situation where Microsoft's Reactive Framework is a far better fit.

Your code would look like this:

```
public class EventsTest
{
    private IDisposable _subscription;

    public EventsTest()
    {
        IoService ioService = new IoService();

        _subscription =
            Observable
                .FromEvent<IoEvent, IoEventArgs>(
                    a => ioService.IoEvent += a, a => ioService.IoEvent -= a)
                .Subscribe(eve =>
                {
                    switch (eve.PortNum)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            LongRunningMethod(eve.Description);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            //invoke a long running method
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                });
    }

    private void LongRunningMethod(string data)
    {
    }
}
```

This should automatically ensure multiple events are queued and will never overlap. If there's problem just drop a `.Synchronize()` call in before the `.Subscribe(...)` and then it'll work perfectly.

When you want to cancel the event just call `_subscription.Dispose()` and it will all be cleaned up for you.

NuGet "Rx-Main" to get the bits you need.